# Using rosservice from webui

Tags: rosservice

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

Does anyone have tried to change parameter of dynamic_reconfigure from webui?

For example , I could't figure out how to change prosilica_diver/set_parameters.
Of course I can change it from command line like below.

```
   rosservice call /prosilica_driver/set_parameters '{config:{ints:[[x_offset,0],[y_offset,0],[width,0],[height,0]]}}'
```

but calling from webui(ros.js) as followings did not works.

```
    gPump.service_call("prosilica_driver/set_parameters",
                       [[["auto_exposure",true]],
                        [["x_offset",pxoffset]],
                        [["trigger_mode","polled"]],
            [["trig_rate",15.0]]
                        ]);
```

thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9920/using-rosservice-from-webui/) by [chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/510/chen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2011-05-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Webui was, at one point, for "internal use only".  At this point it is completely unsupported...

---

Originally posted by [Straszheim](https://answers.ros.org/users/44/straszheim/) with karma: 426 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0